# Can I show / hide meta tags with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

For my site I need to add meta tags for our 3rd party analytics i.e.

```
<meta name="WT_si" content="Content Group" />
```

And basically I want to first figure out the Content Group name based on the url of the page

So in the head tag before I write the meta tag I guess I would like to place some sort of javascript variable in the meta tag for Content group

```
<meta name="WT_si" content="Content Group" />
```

Or I was thinking of doing something like

```
if(contentGroup == "Business)

<meta name="WT_si" content="Content Group" />

else

<meta name="WT_si" content="Corporate" />
```

Is the above possible in javascript in the head with meta tags >

Comment: Sure. But what good would changing the meta tags after the document is loaded do? By then the document has already been consumed.

Comment: Ok so how could I add logic to show correct meta tags on page load

Comment: The analytics script might load in the body of the document and just needs to read the DOM.

Comment: The base tag runs in the head aswell, I was going to put the meta tags before the base tag. I am just trying to figure out how I can put the right meta tags in the head

Comment: This is not a real question since there is no hint of the software that is assumed to consume the `meta` tags. When such software has been identified, with its documentation, the question turns to a simple software-specific coding issue.

Answer (score 1):

To add meta tags to the document's `head` based on a condition with Javascript:

```
var metaTag=document.createElement("meta");
if(contentGroup == "business")
{
    metaTag.content = "Content Group";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
}
else
{
    metaTag.content = "Corporate";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
}
```

Comment: Ok this is what I am looking for ! So will this work once the page is server or only after

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work with jquery

```
$('meta[content]').hide();
```

will add style

```
display:none on the meta tag
```

but I am not sure why would you want to do that?

Comment: I didn't see anything about jQuery in the question

Comment: Also, that's not what the asker wants

Comment: @JanDvorak question was about hiding meta content but you are right its not exactly what he wants